# ByteArray to a byte[] in a intentService?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, firebase-storage

I've searched wide and far for an answer to this and I can't quite cope how to do it.

I'm trying to upload a picture to Firebase using their tutorial (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) for storage. To do this I have created an IntentService to handle all database calls. This is where I run short. I pack my picture from another activity like this;

```
public void sendToFB() {
    mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putByteArray("bitmap", data);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirebaseService.class);
    intent.putExtra("picture", bundle);
    this.startService(intent);
}
```

I then unwrap the bundle in the service;

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    extras = (Bundle) intent.getExtras().get("picture");
    uploadPicToFirebase();
    ...
```

and then I try to paste the bytearray, but I need to convert it to byte and I dont know how inside a service.

```
private void uploadPicToFirebase() {

    // Get the data from an ImageView as bytes
    /*mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
    */
    //Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    byte[] data = extras.getByteArray("picture");

    UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("not ok");
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("helt ok");
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    });
}
```

It ends in an `IllegalArgumentException` of course

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bytes cannot be null

Comment: I would suggest that rather than sending a byte[] through an intent, that you save a temporary file, and pass the file path as a string to the intent service.  Intent extras have a limit that will get reached very quickly especially where images as byte arrays are concerned  - bit more reading .. https://www.neotechsoftware.com/blog/android-intent-size-limit

Comment: Will I reach that file binder limit tho with a compressed bytearray ?

Comment: Depends on the size of the compressed byte[] .. which at runtime you'll never know because every image is different.  I couldn't possibly know the output size of an unknown input size.  My suggestion isn't an answer, that is below, it was only to help solve a potential problem you might face further down the line ... Better to preempt now, and to be honest from a coding perspective it's not a great deal to change. My rule of thumb, only put the minimum amount information/data/extras in an intent as possible, whilst still achieving the same desired outcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mistaken a key:

```java
private void uploadPicToFirebase(){

    // ...

    byte[] data = extras.getByteArray("bitmap");

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Goddamn :/ Thank you!